# Solve one nonlinear equation and a differential one to find out maximum with sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

The two equations I want to solve are the following:

1.:

y and x are user input, so only t and z are unknown

0 = y + t*sqrt((15/3.6)**2 - (x/t)**2) - (abs((30 / 3.6) * (t + z - 25200 - 1800)) + ((30 / 3.6) * (t + z - 25200 - 1800)) / 2)

2.:

d/dt(z) = 0
I want to find out t for the highest z value possible.

I tried multiple commands such as

```
func = y + t*sqrt((15/3.6)**2 - (x/t)**2) - (abs((30 / 3.6) * (t + z - 25200 - 1800)) + ((30 / 3.6) * (t + z - 25200 - 1800)) / 2)
result = dsolve(Derivative(z, t), func)
```

but the output was: ValueError: dsolve() and classify_ode() only work with functions of one variable, not [...]

Question1: Is there a way for python to define z by using t (z= ...)?
If not, is there a way to get rid of abs(), I only wanted (30 / 3.6) * (t + z - 25200 - 1800) to not be negative.

Question2: Can I differentiate that equation z for t?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with sympy, but the issue with your sample code is that you have 2 unknowns, and only 1 equation. So, there's only 3 scenarios:

- Both z and t are 0, you're done
- One of z or t is 0, set that variable to 0 and solve
- Neither z nor t is 0, and so z and t each have their own sets of possible values

So I guess what I'm more specifically answering is: what does your `ValueError` mean.

Here's [another resource I found](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SolveDifferentialEquations) for solving DEs in Python.

Comment: Thanks for anwering. Sorry, maybe I should have worded my question better. Also t and z are both not supposed to be 0. I want z to be the highest number possible but the equation should still be solveable.

Question1: Is there a way for python to define z by using t (z= ...)?
If not, is there a way to get rid of abs(), I only wanted (30 / 3.6) * (t + z - 25200 - 1800) to not be negative.

Question2: Can I differentiate that equation z for t?